# Implement Inbox Functionality in custom cq component?

Tags: aem

We want to develop a smooth-flowing workflow experience (but still use workflows).  Currently, a user needs to use the sidekick to initiate the workflow, then to the inbox, which takes them back to the page to use the sidekick again.  When they go to the inbox, they need to restrict to the model and path of the page.  It would be nice for the user to only have to go to the content page and from there, launch the different workflow forms that need to happen, like a little "inbox" right on the page that is subject to the workflow.

I have written a custom component that can initiate the custom workflow.  The custom component can also query the WorkFlowSession and obtain any active WorkItems for the current page that the component resides (using the WorkItemFilter interface).  What I want to do is provide a link to the user to the next step in the workflow from the custom component, just like the inbox does.
Here is an example output from an WorkItem instance toString method:

```
21.05.2014 09:45:29.300 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 [1400679929160] GET /content/test/mailing1.html HTTP/1.1] org.rand.whatcounts.EmailCampaignCoordinator Found workitem: -----------------------------
WorkItem Id: /etc/workflow/instances/2014-05-21/model_1400679794564399000/workItems/node4_etc_workflow_instances_2014-05-21_model_1400679794564399000
Workflow Id: /etc/workflow/instances/2014-05-21/model_1400679794564399000
Payload: /content/test/mailing1
Payload Type: JCR_PATH
key = historyEntryPath value = /etc/workflow/instances/2014-05-21/model_1400679794564399000/history/1400679924113
key = comment value =
```

My hope is that by using the workflow api items, I can create the link that the user could click on to proceed in the workflow (just like the inbox).

Thanks for listening!
Phillip

Comment: How is what you are doing different from the Workflow tab in the Sidekick? I don't get it.

Comment: The sidekick only allows one to change workflow states.   Yes, one can use the sidekick to initiate a workflow (which I can do also via java code).  However, if your workflow needs to upload a file, or collect some data, you need to use the inbox.  You cannot use the sidekick to get to the form that would allow you to upload a file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to implement this

**Java-Based Solution**
I was able to figure out one way by looking at

```
http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/workflow/components/inbox/list/json.jsp
```

The important part of this jsp is that, given a workItem instance, you can get the path for your next step using the JcrPathBuilderManager:
 pathBuilder.getPath(wi);
Using this, I was able to output a link to the next step in the workflow to the user (without having user go to their inbox).

**Javascript/JSON Based Solution**
I didn't go far with this solution (I didn't write any js) but this was my fall back position if I didn't find the java-solution listed above. Once could implement custom JS in CQ Component that would call the json feed for the user inbox, do some client side filtering (to restrict it to only items related to current page).  The URL to the feed is

```
http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/workflow/content/inbox/list.json?start=0&limit=40
```

Thanks!